# bxSlider not working on first load for Chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css, bxslider

So i use **bxSlider** just as the website shown on this [page](https://bxslider.com/install/), thing is on **first load** the slider arrows show but my images does not show.

On **second load** (page refresh) it works perfectly fine. This issue is only on Chrome.

Edge, Firefox, IE has no issue displaying slider images on first load.

Now i know the snippet works, i cant duplicate the problem within the snippet but here is a link to the page , [click me](https://www.rupert-rothschildvignerons.com/restaurant) , MVC not prefer links to external pages, but as said cant duplicate this? Is this a chrome bug, i cant get a fix?

also i used version `jquery/1.11.0` as my site does, but as can see bellow, dont think the version is the issue.

```html
<html>
<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.12/jquery.bxslider.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.12/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.slider').bxSlider();
    });
  </script>

</head>
<body>

  <div class="slider">
    <div>I am a slide.</div>
    <div>I am another slide.</div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try to add the `bxslider.js` at the end of `body` tag...or try to initialize the slide at `$(window).on("load")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's look like your initialization function `$('.slider').bxSlider()` is executing before your `bxslider.js` load...

...so try to initialize your `$('.slider').bxSlider()` after the page load using `$(window).on("load")`

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
  $('.slider').bxSlider();
})
```

Comment: Thanks , actually works on Chrome and all the other browser!